# LoRaWAN connection between three Raspberry Pi 3s

Tags: hardware, communication

Are LoRaWAN devices able to transmit compressed/zipped JSON files which are 5-10 Kb big?

Furthermore I've been reading up the [LoRaWAN technology](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/lorawan-with-prorf-and-the-things-network/all) to get a better understanding. I would like to have 3 RPIs (A, B and C) where 2 ("A" & "B") of them send zipped/compressed json files to the third one "C". And the plan is to send these json files to a server. Could this be done?

Comment: LoRa is designed for Long Range, slow data rate communications, and LoRaWAN is an implementation of it. Here is a good description of it and its abilities... https://github.com/Fluent-networks/floranet/wiki/LoRaWAN-Overview

Comment: The question does not belong to Raspberry Pi. You should better ask on a LoRaWAN forum.

Comment: @Ingo Is there a LoRaWAN.SX?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What is LoRaWAN.SX? If it is relevant to your question, please edit it.

Comment: @Ingo is there a LoRaWAN StackeXchange (SX) Forum?

Comment: I don't know, see: https://stackexchange.com/sites. At https://www.sparkfun.com/privacy I have found: "*We maintain accounts on various social media platforms, including Facebook, Twitter, Google+, Pinterest, Flickr, GitHub, YouTube, Ello, and Instagram, and Tumblr.*". You may also try at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/. Does the answer on your question help you?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, no, sort of.

I assume you have read the article you linked and found "How to build your own lorawan gateway", with the gateway being raspberry C.

You will also find the datasheet for the RFM69HCW transceiver which [reads](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/General/RFM69HCW-V1.1.pdf): "... features  of  the  RFM69HCW include a **66 byte TX/RX FIFO**, configurable automatic packet handler..."

In those kind of chips the packet size (if enabled) is fixed. If you have split-second accuracy (microcontroller level) you can get away and drive them in 'continuous mode': not something you will be able to do an a raspberry and/or if you want to maintain your mental sanity.

And anyway, even 1 KB would be huge. In general it will be a bad idea from an RF point of view. Your target should be more like 20 bytes per packet!

Your options are:

- Install a whole load of software and have a full stack; maybe some will provide big transfer features (IDK if such a thing exists)
- Get the rid of the whole LoRaWAN stuff altogether, just use the LoRa radios themselves and figure out a way to do the transfer yourself.

Fair access policies will still be an issue, maybe [this](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/forum/t/send-picture-via-lorawan/2407) could interest you.

The outlook seems quite bad to me but we could still wrap up and say yes, it can be done. With some caveats.